# Drag & Drop Magazine Builder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I create a website builder? I want to make drag & drop site builder and researching for tools. don't know which tools are necessary for that.
I want to make like www.joomag.com

Which tool I should use ?

Comment: Which technologies do you have knowledge of? Does one of those enable you to do what you want? Is this something you are going to be doing as a learning exercise for a new technology? There are multiple answers to this question, but the question itself raises the need for more information; and even then, the answers will be more opinion than a definite answer

Comment: I can use HTMl-5 , php and jquery . but the problem is I dont know the structure . Is there any specific language to develop the builder. ? just like jigzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 provides functionality of drag and drop, but you need to know javascript for it. Plus making good designs need css(possibly css3). Then finally to save the result and generate the code, you'll need some server side language.

Comment: Suppose I have to draw the text box on web builder area. is there any specific technology which I can use for that ?

Comment: Javascript mainly. But if you want better looks and interface, you'll have to study 'canvas' tag of HTML5.